# UIButton auto SelfSizing in objective C

Tags: ios, onclick, uibutton, resize

I have some issues with how to auto self sizing native UIButton in ios. OnClick UIButton then button is auto resize with changeable text.

If anyone has a solution so help me.
thanks in advance

code:

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) 

 {

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;     
    NSLog(@"Hide tag");
    UIButton *myView = [self.textView viewWithTag:-1];
    [myView removeFromSuperview];

}
else 
   {

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    NSLog(@"Show tag");
    UIButton *myView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 40.0f, 20.0f)];
    [myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [myView setTag:-1];
    [self.textView addSubview:myView];
     NSLog(@"add tag");

    self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", self.textView.text,cell.textLabel.text, @"\n"];

}

 }
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to show some code?  Perhaps what you've tried so far?

Comment: on click single uitableview cell then show text on UIButton and it is selfsizing also and text hide again click on cell.